# How do I increment a variable that has a word within the variable name?

Tags: batch-file

It seems like a simple resolution so what I'm trying to do is to get all the contents within a .txt file per line and create them as a variable.
From there I would like to output each variable that is collected over and over.

Example:

```
Contents1
Contents2
Contents3
```

What I currently have in my script that I found elsewhere was that it would grab each of those and store them as:

```
var1
var2
var3
```

Essentially it would be:

```
var1 = Contents1
var2 = Contents2
var3 = Contents3
```

However within my loop, I can't seem to grab var1, var2, var3, etc.
I'm trying to increment each var because there's over 100+ variables from each file.

```
@echo off

REM Enable Delayed Expansion for !Variables!
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Get file contents and store them per variable ex: var1, var2, var3
set VarList=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
    SET /A VarList=!VarList! + 1
)
set var

SET TierLevel=Common
SET Type=Armor
SET EnchantName=%TierLevel%_%Type%

set Counter=0

REM For this, there would be 3 variable outputs per body for each enchantment
REM However the lower the tier, the less there will be.
REM Minimum 1 & Max 3
set /A Amount=%VarList%/3


:repeat
REM Use all the variables [With the 3 per body] until each type is filled
REM Final output should be something such as:
REM Common_Armor1 -> Common_Armor5
REM Within Common_Armor1 it will contain:
REM Sharpness, Fireaspect, and Smite
REM Within Common_Armor2 it will contain:
REM Sharpness, Fireaspect and Looting

set /A INeedThisToIncrement+=%var%1

IF "!Amount!"=="!Counter!" (
    Echo All complete!
    pause
    exit
        ) else (
echo      %EnchantName%%Counter%: >> output.txt
echo          %INeedThisToIncrement% >> output.txt
        )
        set /A Counter=Counter+1
        goto :repeat
```

The part where I'm stuck is...

I need the variable: INeedThisToIncrement
to be var1, then increment output the variables: var2, then var3, var4, var5, etc.

So it needs to increment each time.
I tried to make something relative to var+%%a or something like that, however it would output the name var + the numbers to increment.

It outputs this via console:

> ```
> VarList=9
>
> All complete
>
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

The output.txt contains:

> ```
>  Common_Armor0: 
>      1 
>  Common_Armor1: 
>      2 
>  Common_Armor2: 
>      3
> ```

Does anyone have any idea how to increment var1 so each loop would output var2, var3, var4, etc?

Comment: Please also note that `DOS` is the OS from the 1980/1990s, and I don't think you are using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off

REM Enable Delayed Expansion for !Variables!
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Get file contents and store them per variable ex: var1, var2, var3
set VarList=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
    SET /A VarList=!VarList! + 1
    set "var!VarList!=%%A"
)
set var
pause
```

And then inside your repeat loop

```
set "INeedThisToIncrement+=!var%counter%!"
```

And start your counter from 1

Comment: Thank you! :D

I modified it slightly and it works great now.
I went to add some additions, however I realized there was one other issue.

If I were to try to increment and echo out !INeedThisToIncrement! again within the if statement... it wouldn't increment within the bracket.

Is there any way to increment a variable within the if statement? I saw it work in for loops, however I don't believe I need one of those and honestly don't know how to make one considering most seemed to look at each variable within a file.

Thank you for the help! :D

Comment: Okay it took me a while to get working. Entirely my fault.

Essentially what I was doing was... Incrementing via counter and I never added the addition to the counter. So I was beyond confused thinking it was in it's own case.

So I moved it into another loop... still didn't work.

After adding on the counter each time it works perfect. Thank you so much for you help! :D